# @IntDef Android support annontation with Jackson deserializing

Tags: android, json, jackson, android-support-library

Using JacksonAnnotations along with Android Support Annotations. My POJO is:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Schedule {
    public static final int SUNDAY = 0;
    public static final int MONDAY = 1;
    public static final int TUESDAY = 2;
    public static final int WEDNESDAY = 3;
    public static final int THURSDAY = 4;
    public static final int FRIDAY = 5;
    public static final int SATURDAY = 6;

    private Integer weekday;

    public Schedule() {
    }

    @Weekday
    public Integer getWeekday() {
        return weekday;
    }

    public void setWeekday(@Weekday Integer weekday) {
        this.weekday = weekday;
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @IntDef({SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY})
    public @interface Weekday {}
}
```

From backed i get object:

```
{"schedule":{"weekday":"MONDAY"}}
```

What i want is to map Weekday to it's integer value defined in constants. Is there any way i can achieve this?

**Update**: The main purpose is optimization (**You should strictly avoid using enums on Android** like it said [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Overhead)).

Comment: Write a custom json deserializer and make the change in there between the string provided and the int value required.

Comment: Of course i know about custom deserializers and @JsonCreator. Just looking for more "elgant" solution.

Comment: Why do you use Integer instead of int ? Boxing makes your code even less efficient than enums.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can count on weekdays not growing out of control, creating a static map seems like a pretty clean solution. Providing a `@JsonCreator` factory named `fromString` will work with Jackson and will also [play nicely with JAX-RS](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2153):

```
public class Schedule {
    ...
    private static final ImmutableMap<String, Schedule> WEEKDAY_TO_INT_MAP =
            ImmutableMap.<String, Schedule>builder()
                .put("SUNDAY", withIntWeekday(0))
                .put("MONDAY", withIntWeekday(1))
                .put("TUESDAY", withIntWeekday(2))
                .put("WEDNESDAY", withIntWeekday(3))
                .put("THURSDAY", withIntWeekday(4))
                .put("FRIDAY", withIntWeekday(5))
                .put("SATURDAY", withIntWeekday(6))
                .build();

    public static Schedule withIntWeekday(int weekdayInt) {
        Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
        schedule.setWeekday(weekdayInt);
        return schedule;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Schedule fromString(String weekday) {
        return WEEKDAY_TO_INT_MAP.get(weekday);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but why not do something like this:

```
public class Schedule {
    public enum Weekday {
        SUNDAY(0),
        MONDAY(1),
        TUESDAY(2),
        WEDNESDAY(3),
        THURSDAY(4),
        FRIDAY(5),
        SATURDAY(6);

        private final Integer weekday;

        Weekday(Integer weekday) {
            this.weekday = weekday;
        }

        public Integer getWeekday() {
            return weekday;
        }
    }

    private Weekday weekday;

    public Integer getWeekday() {
        return weekday.getWeekday();
    }

    public void setWeekday(Weekday weekday) {
        this.weekday = weekday;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not an android developer. So I just learned something new. Thanks. I was about to suggest `Sam B`'s solution and as I wrote it, I saw enums can do better. If for android enums are forbidden - go with Sam's solution. Or an abbreviation of it having an `ImmutableMap<String, Int>` instead of schedule.

Comment: U think it will be more efficient than using enum?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know. I am not aware of efficiency issues in android. I am a mere Java developer :-) I know that in pure Java - enums are considered an optimisation. See for instance EnumMap vs Map.

Answer (score 0):

If the backend is returning `"MONDAY"` as a string then you probably should not be using `@IntDef` because you will have to manage converting `"MONDAY"` into an integer value.

I would try using the `@StringDef` annotation instead that way you won't have to worry about any sort of conversion between the backend and the client app. The only catch is you need to have reliable responses from your backend and agree upon the naming conventions ahead of time.

If you change the type from `@IntDef` to `@StringDef` it would look like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Schedule {
    public static final String SUNDAY = "SUNDAY";
    public static final String MONDAY = "MONDAY";
    public static final String TUESDAY = "TUESDAY";
    public static final String WEDNESDAY = "WEDNESDAY";
    public static final String THURSDAY = "THURSDAY";
    public static final String FRIDAY = "FRIDAY";
    public static final String SATURDAY = "SATURDAY";

    private String weekday;

    public Schedule() {
    }

    @Weekday
    public String getWeekday() {
        return weekday;
    }

    public void setWeekday(@Weekday String weekday) {
        this.weekday = weekday;
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @StringDef({SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY})
    public @interface Weekday {}
}
```

Comment: I still need the .ordinal() value from enum (number of weekday) so this not a solution for me.

Comment: If you need the `.ordinal()` value then it would make the most sense to use an enum. Even though an enum is more expensive than an `@IntDef`, it is less expensive then making another data structure which would be you only other option. It looks like UriShalit has the best answer.

Comment: I don't think so. Event setter with ifs comparing value string ands assigning and ints would be lighter. UriShalit's answer is what i have now which i want to optimize.

Comment: You're right that would be lighter, yet it doesn't seem simpler. I think you might already have the simplest solution and unless you need your application to be very performant you might want to stick with how how it is.

Answer (score 0):

The elegant solution is using an Enum.

The efficient solution is writing a custom serializer that maps a week day string to an int and vice versa using switch statements.

You could also access the values in the `StringDef` annotation using reflection in your serializer, but that will be slower and less readable.